# nested list of number array in a container

Tags: arrays, flutter, listview, dart

I was trying to use ListView Builder to build a container with numbers displaying as in matrix kind of order. But somehow I unable to receive the same in the container. Please help me review this code and mention where am I going wrong or what needs to be implemented. Herewith I am attaching my code snippet.

[This is what I am trying to build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rkF2.png)

```
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Ticket extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TicketState createState() => _TicketState();
}

class _TicketState extends State<Ticket> {
  
  List tick = [
    {
      'tickets':[
        [
          [1,5,7,0,8,9,7,74,9],
          [1,15,7,10,8,79,27,74,9],
          [71,5,7,20,18,9,77,74,79],
        ],
        [
          [21,5,7,80,8,9,7,74,49],
          [31,15,7,10,18,79,7,74,19],
          [71,5,7,20,18,79,77,74,29],
        ],
      ]
    },
  ];

  
  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var h = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var w = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: tick.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index){
                return Center(
                  child: Container(
                    height: h/5,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Center(child: Text('${tick[index]['tickets']}'))
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
                },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[This is a kind of output I am receiving.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ytc0c.jpg)

Comment: Can you mention what output are you getting with the current code?

Comment: Please check I have attached the output that I am receiving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your data structure it's a bit complex because has a list that holds a map and other nested lists inside the map, you need to do a couple of iterations over each list to get the expected result. You can try something like the code bellow, that you can test at [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/). See the comments in the code to understand better what each iteration does.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Ticket extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TicketState createState() => _TicketState();
}

class _TicketState extends State<Ticket> {
  List tick = [
    {
      'tickets': [
        [
          [11, 5, 7, 10, 28, 9, 7, 74, 59],
          [1, 15, 7, 10, 8, 79, 27, 74, 9],
          [71, 5, 7, 20, 18, 9, 77, 74, 79],
        ],
        [
          [21, 5, 7, 80, 8, 9, 7, 74, 49],
          [31, 15, 7, 10, 18, 79, 7, 74, 19],
          [71, 5, 7, 20, 18, 79, 77, 74, 29],
        ],
      ]
    },
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var h = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var w = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(
                color: Colors.black,
              )),
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: tick.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                  List tripleNumbersList = [];
                  List<Widget> cells = [];
                  List<Widget> rows = [];
                  //Get the lenght of the list inside the 'tickets' map
                  int ticketsCount = tick[index]['tickets'].length;

                  //Iterates over the lists inside the 'tickets' map
                  for (int i = 0; i < ticketsCount; i++) {
                    //Get the lists of lists inside the 'tickets' map
                    tripleNumbersList = tick[index]['tickets'][i];
                    //Iterates over each list with other 3 lists
                    for (int j = 0; j < tripleNumbersList.length; j++) {
                      //Get one of the 3 lists
                      List<int> list = tripleNumbersList[j];
                      //Iterates over the list of numbers
                      for (int k = 0; k < list.length; k++) {
                        //Adds a Widget to 'cells; list for each number
                        cells.add(Container(
                            height: 40,
                            width: 40,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(
                                color: Colors.black,
                              ),
                              //color: Colors.pink
                            ),
                            child: GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  print('Working');
                                },
                                child: Text(
                                  ' ${list[k]}  ',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 22.0,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                ))));
                      }
                      //Adds the list of 'cells' in the 'rows' list
                      rows.add(Row(children: cells));
                      cells = [];
                    }
                    //Adds a empty row to make space
                    rows.add(Row(children: [
                      Container(
                        height: 10,
                      )
                    ]));
                  }

                  return Center(
                    child: Container(
                      height: h,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                        //color: Colors.pink
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        //Adds the list of rows to the column
                        children: rows,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Ticket(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The code is working fine with the logic but then it is not building two different cards.
I was trying to replicate the image

Comment: This is because you need define which layout do you want. By example, in the line `cells.add(Center(child: GestureDetector(`, instead of a Center you can add a Container with a border. I used a Center with Text just as example of how to implement result with the 3 lines.

Comment: I edited the code replacing the Center with a Container. Test to see how it looks.

Comment: This looks as same as the image.

Comment: Nice. Now you can make the adjustments and improvements that you want.

Comment: Okay...What if the list tick is getting it's data from an API... So how will I do that...  I have created a model class for the API response but am unable to display the data in the container

Comment: You need to parse the response data and then do the same thing. If the structure of the json is different of the structure that you wrote in this question you need to adapt for the structure you receive from API. If you don't know how to parse json, you have to make some research in the Flutter docs or  some tutorials of how to parse json, or make another question with a different matter.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62851522/unable-to-display-the-list-of-array-from-an-api-in-a-container.         Please check this....I have made another question for it

Comment: I tried parsing the Json data....but I messed up with the code

Comment: I answered the other question, but your api sometimes doesn't returns response. You need to check this. But then it returns a response the code is working.

Comment: If you hit the API twice it sends the data right!!!

Comment: Yes, this is what is happening.

Comment: How can I reach you if I face some other kinda doubt in flutter. The way you explain is pretty clean and clear as because you comment out the thing

Comment: And can you explain me where was I going wrong and what more concepts do I need to clear out

Comment: When you're programming is normal find some errors or some complex implementation. To learn more, the ideal is you try to solve the problems by yourself first, in a way that you will getting more experience and knowledge about the language you're using. And here in the stackoverflow, as the internet as well, there are a lot of people that can help you if you get a point where you can't advance. But there's also many tutorials and examples in the internet to research and see how other peoples implements something in different ways because can have more than one way to solve the same problem.

Comment: @JRamnos
Yes I completely agree with your suggestion and I always try to implement the same but most of the time it gets messed up when dealing with such a list of arrays.
As soon as you comment out the steps, it really helped me a lot.

Comment: @JRamnos29 I was successful adding the gesture detectors to each of the text widgets.
Made it possible because of your comment.

But got stuck to some other errors as well.
Herewith attaching an another problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62862222/trying-not-to-display-a-specific-number-from-a-api-data