# Unable to display the list of array from an API in a container

Tags: arrays, api, flutter, dart

I was trying to display the received data from API in the container but ended up with some errors, so I used the static method to display the API data received well-got success there.
But I cannot figure out what is going wrong with my process.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class Ticket extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TicketState createState() => _TicketState();
}

class _TicketState extends State<Ticket> {

  var nos;

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    _getNumbers();
  }
  _getNumbers() async{
    var result = await http.post('https://tickets-qzd55332wa-de.a.run.app/generateTickets?ticketsRequired=1');
    print(result.body);

  }
    //API RESPONSE(This is what I have made it locally but I want to fetch the same from the API itself)
  List tick = [
 // This is the exact output of the data fetched from the API
    {
      'tickets': [
        [
          [11, 5, 7, 10, 28, 9, 7, 74, 59],
          [1, 15, 7, 10, 8, 79, 27, 74, 9],
          [71, 5, 7, 20, 18, 9, 77, 74, 79],
        ],
        [
          [21, 5, 7, 80, 8, 9, 7, 74, 49],
          [31, 15, 7, 10, 18, 79, 7, 74, 19],
          [71, 5, 7, 20, 18, 79, 77, 74, 29],
        ],
      ]
    },
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var h = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var w = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.black,
                  )),
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: tick.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                  List tripleNumbersList = [];
                  List<Widget> cells = [];
                  List<Widget> rows = [];
                  //Get the lenght of the list inside the 'tickets' map
                  int ticketsCount = tick[index]['tickets'].length;

                  //Iterates over the lists inside the 'tickets' map
                  for (int i = 0; i < ticketsCount; i++) {
                    //Get the lists of lists inside the 'tickets' map
                    tripleNumbersList = tick[index]['tickets'][i];
                    //Iterates over each list with other 3 lists
                    for (int j = 0; j < tripleNumbersList.length; j++) {
                      //Get one of the 3 lists
                      List<int> list = tripleNumbersList[j];
                      //Iterates over the list of numbers
                      for (int k = 0; k < list.length; k++) {
                        //Adds a Widget to 'cells; list for each number
                        cells.add(Container(
                            height: 40,
                            width: 40,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(
                                color: Colors.black,
                              ),
                              //color: Colors.pink
                            ),
                            child: GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  print('Working');
                                },
                                child: Text(
                                  ' ${list[k]}  ',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 22.0,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                ))));
                      }
                      //Adds the list of 'cells' in the 'rows' list
                      rows.add(Row(children: cells));
                      cells = [];
                    }
                    //Adds a empty row to make space
                    rows.add(Row(children: [
                      Container(
                        height: 20,
                      )
                    ]));
                  }

                  return Center(
                    child: Container(
                      height: h,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                        //color: Colors.pink
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        //Adds the list of rows to the column
                        children: rows,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the object file that I made using the response of the API.

```
Tickets ticketsFromJson(String str) => Tickets.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String ticketsToJson(Tickets data) => json.encode(data.toJson());
class Tickets {
  Tickets({
    this.tickets,
  });

  List<List<List<int>>> tickets;

  factory Tickets.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      Tickets(
        tickets: List<List<List<int>>>.from(
            json["tickets"].map((x) => List<List<int>>.from(
                x.map((x) => List<int>.from(x.map((x) => x)))))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
      {
        "tickets": List<dynamic>.from(tickets.map((x) => List<dynamic>.from(
            x.map((x) => List<dynamic>.from(x.map((x) => x)))))),
      };
}
```

Please help me out with what is wrong with my code and how to display the number as [in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVr1j.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an API request you need wait for the result and then try to parse the result. And since the model created from the json return a list with nested lists, the iteration is almost the same as the hardcoded data structure. I made some changes in the code to make it work, but sometimes your API doesn't seems not available to requests. You need check this. See the comments in the code to understand the changes made:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class Ticket {
  Ticket({
    this.tickets,
  });

  List<List<List<int>>> tickets;

  factory Ticket.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Ticket(
        tickets: List<List<List<int>>>.from(json["tickets"].map((x) =>
            List<List<int>>.from(
                x.map((x) => List<int>.from(x.map((x) => x)))))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "tickets": List<dynamic>.from(tickets.map((x) => List<dynamic>.from(
            x.map((x) => List<dynamic>.from(x.map((x) => x)))))),
      };
}

class TicketPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TicketPageState createState() => _TicketPageState();
}

class _TicketPageState extends State<TicketPage> {
  var nos;
  Ticket ticketList;

  String apiResult;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getNumbers();
  }

  _getNumbers() async {
    var result = await http
        .post(
            'https://tickets-qzd55332wa-de.a.run.app/generateTickets?ticketsRequired=2')
        .then((result) {
      //Waits for the API response and assigns to apiResult variable
      setState(() {
        apiResult = result.body;
      });
    });
  }

  // List tick = [
  //   {
  //     'tickets': [
  //       [
  //         [11, 5, 7, 10, 28, 9, 7, 74, 59],
  //         [1, 15, 7, 10, 8, 79, 27, 74, 9],
  //         [71, 5, 7, 20, 18, 9, 77, 74, 79],
  //       ],
  //       [
  //         [21, 5, 7, 80, 8, 9, 7, 74, 49],
  //         [31, 15, 7, 10, 18, 79, 7, 74, 19],
  //         [71, 5, 7, 20, 18, 79, 77, 74, 29],
  //       ],
  //     ]
  //   },
  // ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var h = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var w = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    if (apiResult == null) {
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    } else {
      //Get an instance of Ticket from the API assigned to apiResponse variable
      ticketList = Ticket.fromJson(json.decode(apiResult));
      print('Tickets: ${ticketList.tickets}');

      return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.black,
                )),
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: ticketList.tickets.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                    List tripleNumbersList = [];
                    List<Widget> cells = [];
                    List<Widget> rows = [];

                    //Get the lists of lists inside the 'tickets' list
                    tripleNumbersList = ticketList.tickets[index];
                    //Iterates over each list with other 3 lists
                    for (int j = 0; j < tripleNumbersList.length; j++) {
                      //Get one of the 3 lists
                      List<int> list = tripleNumbersList[j];
                      //Iterates over the list of numbers
                      for (int k = 0; k < list.length; k++) {
                        //Adds a Widget to 'cells; list for each number
                        cells.add(Container(
                            height: 35,
                            width: 35,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(
                                color: Colors.black,
                              ),
                              //color: Colors.pink
                            ),
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                print('Working');
                              },
                              child: list[k] != 0
                                  ? Text(
                                      ' ${list[k]}  ',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 18.0,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    )
                                  : Text(''),
                            )));
                      }
                      //Adds the list of 'cells' in the 'rows' list
                      rows.add(Row(children: cells));
                      cells = [];
                    }
                    //Adds a empty row to make space
                    rows.add(Row(children: [
                      Container(
                        height: 10,
                      )
                    ]));

                    return Center(
                      child: Container(
                        height: h / 3,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                          //color: Colors.pink
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          //Adds the list of rows to the column
                          children: rows,
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: TicketPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The above code is actually printing two more containers with the same output twice.

Comment: What do you mean by printing two more containers? For me it's printing normal.

Comment: Each ticket is of 3*9.    So when ticketsRequired=2 it is must only show 3 ticket with each ticket of 3*9...instead of this it is showing 9 tickets with 3*9 order

Comment: This [result](https://imgur.com/a/RGm4Fvb) it's what i got when changed the API request to `ticketsRequired=2`.

Comment: I think I got a solution to this...       it Should be.    itemCount: tickets.lenght instead of  itemCount: ticketlist.tickets.lenght

Comment: Give it a scroll it prints more

Comment: I edited the answer. The list it was duplicated cause the `ListView.builder` already does an iteration. So to solve the problem the outer iteration was removed. Now it prints just the tickets once.

Comment: @JRamnos29 Please help me with this issue, if you don't mind doing so.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63102887/unable-to-save-the-data-from-the-textfields-forms-in-the-firebase

Comment: Hey!!
Would appreciate if you could just have a look at this problem that I am facing
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68603763/i-am-trying-to-store-the-authorization-token-fetched-from-the-rest-api-and-then