# Trying not to display a specific number from a API data

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart

I was trying not to display the number zero[0] but somehow it captured the number and displayed it over in the field.
And I thought that it would display up with the API result but what actually it is doing is that
API result * 3
It is printing the API result three times.....

```
import 'package:ample/main.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class Ticket {
  Ticket({
    this.tickets,
  });

  List<List<List<int>>> tickets;

  factory Ticket.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Ticket(
    tickets: List<List<List<int>>>.from(json["tickets"].map((x) =>
    List<List<int>>.from(
        x.map((x) => List<int>.from(x.map((x) => x)))))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "tickets": List<dynamic>.from(tickets.map((x) => List<dynamic>.from(
        x.map((x) => List<dynamic>.from(x.map((x) => x)))))),
  };
}

class TicketPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TicketPageState createState() => _TicketPageState();
}

class _TicketPageState extends State<TicketPage> {
  var nos;
  Ticket ticketList;
  String apiResult;
 // bool isActive = true;

  Map<String, bool> cellStatus = {};

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getNumbers();
  }

  _getNumbers() async {
    var result = await http
        .post(
        'https://tickets-qzd55332wa-de.a.run.app/generateTickets?ticketsRequired=2')
        .then((result) {
      //Waits for the API response and assigns to apiResult variable
      setState(() {
        apiResult = result.body;
      });
    });
  }

  // List tick = [
  //   {
  //     'tickets': [
  //       [
  //         [11, 5, 7, 10, 28, 9, 7, 74, 59],
  //         [1, 15, 7, 10, 8, 79, 27, 74, 9],
  //         [71, 5, 7, 20, 18, 9, 77, 74, 79],
  //       ],
  //       [
  //         [21, 5, 7, 80, 8, 9, 7, 74, 49],
  //         [31, 15, 7, 10, 18, 79, 7, 74, 19],
  //         [71, 5, 7, 20, 18, 79, 77, 74, 29],
  //       ],
  //     ]
  //   },
  // ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var h = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var w = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    if (apiResult == null) {
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    } else {
      //Get an instance of Ticket from the API assigned to apiResponse variable
      ticketList = Ticket.fromJson(json.decode(apiResult));
      print('Tickets: ${ticketList.tickets}');

      //bool isActive = true;

      return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: ticketList.tickets.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                  List tripleNumbersList = [];
                  List<Widget> cells = [];
                  List<Widget> rows = [];
                  //Get the lenght of the list 'tickets' of the Ticket class
                  int ticketsCount = ticketList.tickets.length;

                  //Iterates over the lists inside the 'tickets' list of the Ticket class
                  for (int i = 0; i < ticketsCount; i++) {
                    //Get the lists of lists inside the 'tickets' list
                    tripleNumbersList = ticketList.tickets[i];
                    //Iterates over each list with other 3 lists
                    for (int j = 0; j < tripleNumbersList.length; j++) {
                      //Get one of the 3 lists
                      List<int> list = tripleNumbersList[j];
                      //Iterates over the list of numbers
                      for (int k = 0; k < list.length; k++) {
                        //Adds a Widget to 'cells; list for each number
                        cells.add(Center(
                          child: Container(
                              height: 45,
                              width: 35,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border.all(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                ),
                                color: Colors.pink
                              ),

                              child: GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    if (cellStatus['$i$j$k']?? true) {
                                      print('Working');
                                      setState(() {
                                        cellStatus.addAll({'$i$j$k':false});
                                      });
                                    }
                                  },
                                  child: Text(
                                    ' ${list[k]}  ',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 18.0,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                  ),
                              ),
                          ),
                        ));
                      }
                      //Adds the list of 'cells' in the 'rows' list
                      rows.add(Row(children: cells));
                      cells = [];
                    }
                    //Adds a empty row to make space
                    rows.add(Row(children: [
                      Container(
                        height: 30,
                      )
                    ]));
                  }

                  return Center(
                    child: Container(
                      height: h,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                        //color: Colors.red // covers the big box
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        children: rows,
                      )
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

I do not know where am I going wrong to do so...
Please help me with the algorithm to do so...Failed quite a couple of times

Comment: @JRamnos29 please have a look into this.
Got stuck again

Comment: In which line you are trying to not print the zeros? And what you want to put in the place where the list has zero?

Comment: Where ever in the API response in the array there is zero.       Instead of zero print a icon or null.

Comment: https://images.app.goo.gl/8KndxuaA7zPMemkFA.                  Check this image...the blank spaces each ticket is a zero.....and that's what I am trying to get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To not print the zeros you need just to do a simple check where you are printing the Text widget with the numbers, inside the GestureDetector, like this:

```
GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
            if (cellStatus['$i$j$k']?? true) {
                print('Working');
                setState(() {
                   cellStatus.addAll({'$i$j$k':false});
                });
            }
        },
        //Check if the value if different of zero
        child: list[k] != 0 
             //If different of zero prints the number
             ? Text( ' ${list[k]}  ', style: TextStyle( fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold), )
             //Otherwise, if equal zero, prints an empty text
             : Text(''),
)
```